# Secure way to update Date & Time of a Linux Embedded Device

Tags: linux, date, ssl, ntp, timezone

I have a Linux (4.9.171) machine running on ARM Cortex-A processor. The system has internet connection and talks to my server over SSL. At the first boot, I can configure the date and time to it. However, if my system restarts, it won't have a right time and SSL connection can fail in "Certification Path Validation Algo". I need a way to keep my system time up-to date (few seconds precision will be fine).

My system doesn't have RTC and I don't want to use NTP as it is not secure and anyone can be MITM and give me compromised certificates to attack my system.

I also researched about NTPSec and NTS but they aren't mature now.

Is there any standard way for this problem statement?